# Create SQLite Database in Qt (C++)

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite, database-connection

I'm trying to create a SQLite database in Qt. This is the code that I have:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("C:\\Users\\Tanner\\Desktop\\db.sqlite");

    return a.exec();
}
```

However, it doesn't work. This is the output I receive:

> C:\Users\Tanner\qt\sqltest-build-desktop..\sqltest\main.cpp:8: error:
>   undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN12QSqlDatabase17defaultConnectionE'
>
> C:\Users\Tanner\qt\sqltest-build-desktop..\sqltest\main.cpp:8: error:
>   undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN12QSqlDatabase11addDatabaseERK7QStringS2_'
>
> C:\Users\Tanner\qt\sqltest-build-desktop..\sqltest\main.cpp:8: error:
>   undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN12QSqlDatabaseD1Ev'
>
> C:\Users\Tanner\qt\sqltest-build-desktop..\sqltest\main.cpp:9: error:
>   undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN12QSqlDatabase15setDatabaseNameERK7QString'
>
> C:\Users\Tanner\qt\sqltest-build-desktop..\sqltest\main.cpp:11:
>   error: undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN12QSqlDatabaseD1Ev'
>
> C:\Users\Tanner\qt\sqltest-build-desktop..\sqltest\main.cpp:11:
>   error: undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN12QSqlDatabaseD1Ev'
>
> :-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong as this is the first time I have tried to work with a database in C++/Qt. Any help in creating a database is greatly appreciated! I added an extra slash in the filepath because the compiler kept complaining about character escaping. Could the the extra slashes have anything to do with it? If so, how can I enter the path without it thinking I'm trying to escape the next character.

Comment: It's a linker error, not a compiler error. Make sure you link against the sqlite libraries.

Comment: What are your linker settings? Do you link against the QtSql lib?

Comment: No, I don't. How can I do this? Bart, I'm trying to learn how to use SQLite as a suggestion from your answer to my last question but I haven't been able to find much documentation. How can I link against the SQLite libraries?

Comment: Since you're using Qt, things are slightly different I think. You don't directly link against SQLite, but against Qt's QtSql4.lib (assuming you're using version 4). Qt uses a "driver" model in which it will load a SQL DLL based on your settings (SQLITE, MYSQL, etc.) So try linking against the QtSql lib first and see if that works. I'm not 100% sure, but I won't be far off. [This link might be useful](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/sql-driver.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After not getting it to work, I checked with the Qt Community Forum and it seems that all I was missing was

> QT += sql

in the .pro file

Here is the forum post: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/8262/

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. When I was trying to create Qt database I got several errors from linker and any guesses how to solve them failed until I stumbeled upon your question, interesting to notice that requirement to include the statement in .pro isn`t given in Qt documentation. I have similar situation with QtNetwork, which also should be included in .pro , but this was mentioned in documentation

Answer (score 3):

The errors you're seeing are not compiler errors, but linker errors. The error itself is not related to SQLite, but to Qt. You most likely don't link against QtSql4.lib (the 4 might be a different version number). Doing that will most likely make the errors you're seeing go away.

As an answer to your comment/question, you don't (on your application level) have to worry about SQLite at all. Since you use Qt's SQL functionality, this will be taken care of (and "hidden") by Qt. Qt uses so called [database drivers](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/sql-driver.html) which are essentially plugins it loads based on what you have specified in your code. So an SQLite driver in your case.

If this driver has not been created when you installed Qt, you might have to build it yourself. You can follow the instructions you can find in the link I have provided above.

P.s. you have correctly handled the "character escaping" issue. This is not the cause of your current problems.

Comment: I don't seem to have the "%QTDIR%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\sqlite" folder on my computer. The command prompt cannot find %QTDIR%, and if I go to the folder where QT is on my computer, there is no "src" folder.

Comment: %QTDIR% refers to the environment variable QTDIR. This variable usually points to where you have installed Qt. (You might have to create that variable yourself. I seem to remember I did). Did you install a binary release by any chance? I personally always build Qt from sources, so I don't know what the binary release looks like, but it might explain why you have no src folder.

Comment: Yes I did install it from the binary on QT's website.

Comment: Do you at least have a directory "%QTDIR%\plugins\sqldrivers", where QTDIR is your Qt directory? And if so, does it contain libs and dlls for qsqlite? And btw, did you resolve the linking errors?

Comment: No I have not resolved the linking errors because I don't have the appropriate files to build the plugin. No, I do not have that directory. How can I go about obtaining these files?

Comment: You may have to download the Qt source package and build it that way - I know I had to for the ODBC drivers.

Comment: Read my answer carefully. The QtSql4.lib is not the plugin. You might already have that (I'm not sure about your Qt install) and be able to solve your linker errors. However, you will indeed still need the plugins. Like I said, I build Qt from the sources. I never looked at another way, so perhaps someone else might suggest something easier. I just [grab the zip, unpack, run configure, go drink coffee, run nmake and get some sleep](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/install-win.html). ;)

Comment: Alright Bart. I guess I'll install it from the source and see how that goes. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Edit: The problem was a missing line in the .pro file

Comment: That is a Qt and qmake specific way to specify a dependency on the QtSql module and will cause the correct modules to be linked in. So apparently you must have had the modules on your system anyway. But the answer still holds.